# Swift - Vapor - replace plus sign with %2B in request parameter

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, postman, vapor

I have a Vapor server-side app written in Swift with endpoint validate that takes password param. Password can contain plus (+) sign and it should be handled correctly.

Currently when password contains plus sign it is being converted to whitespace after I extract password with "req.query.get".

What I consider doing is to encode password with percent encoding and replace plus sign with %2B, so that plus sign is present in received password from postman which later I need to validate.

My code:

```
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {

    app.get("validate") { req -> Int in
        
        do {
            var password = try req.query.get(String.self, at: "password")
            if !isValidPassword(&password) { return 400 }
        } catch {
            return 400
        }
        
        return 200
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never send a password using the url

Comment: @LeoDabus it's only for studying purposes

Comment: Anyway. If you want to learn you should only send its hash. I would also use a shared key to encrypt the data to send / receive it.

Comment: Take a look at Crypto framework

Comment: @LeoDabus But the point for now is not in working with password, but in validating the request field with plus sign

Comment: The plus sign in a url might be interpreted as a space as well. Check how google compose its url when there is a space at the search query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encode a plus sign into the URL the client should send it as `%2B`

It's the clients responsibility to distinguish between a `+` and a   when sending them in the URL